# Ruby: add a method to a module from a separate file and autoload it

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the Sorcery library in a rails app. One of its modules is for external authentication, and I need to add a method to that module.

The existing code is [here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/controller/submodules/external.rb), I want to add the `add_provider_to_user` method from [this patch](https://github.com/foohey/sorcery/commit/599b08a70e1a40068a7520aececfd3b30ae29be9).

So, I added a file to my `lib/modules` directory, which I've told rails to autoload. The file is called `sorcery_extension.rb` and it looks like this:

```
module Sorcery
  module Controller
    module Submodules
      module External
        module InstanceMethods
          protected

          # If user is logged, he can add all available providers into his account
          def add_provider_to_user(provider)
            provider_name = provider.to_sym
            provider = Config.send(provider_name)
            user_hash = provider.get_user_hash
            config = user_class.sorcery_config

            user = current_user.send(config.authentications_class.to_s.downcase.pluralize).build(config.provider_uid_attribute_name => user_hash[:uid], config.provider_attribute_name => provider)
            user.save(:validate => false)

            return user
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This didn't work. I get `undefined method error` in my controller (where calling the other sorcery methods works fine).

So, my basic understanding of ruby is you can add methods to an object or module at any time... I think I've copied the nesting of the modules correctly in the file. Do I need to name the module file something different? I'm not really sure how to do this kind of thing, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is never `require`d. You can double check this by typing in the console:

```
Sorcery::Controller::Submodules::External::InstanceMethods.method_defined?(:add_provider_to_user)
  # => will return false, you want true
```

The reason is that auloading only happens when a constant is unknown in which case Rails will try to autoload it from the different autoloaded paths.

You have to require your file explicitly (e.g. from a file in initializer) and things will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Rails convention on requires is that for every module it looks in a directory of the same name.

For your example

```
module Sorcery
  module Controller
    module Submodules
      module External
       module InstanceMethods
```

If you want to put the module in the lib directory. When it goes to "autorequire" Rails would be expecting it in this path

```
lib/sorcery/controller/submodules/external/instance_methods.rb
```

This is why its generally good convention to keep your module nesting shallow. ~ 2 levels deep.